# Does this specific exercise lend itself well to a 'functional style' design pattern?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

Say we have an array of one dimensional javascript objects contained in a file Array.json for which the key schema isn't known, that is the keys aren't known until the file is read.

Then we wish to output a CSV file with a header or first entry which is a comma delimited set of keys from all of the objects.

Each next line of the file should contain the comma separated values which correspond to each key from the file.

Array.json

```
[
    abc:123,
    xy:"yz",
    s12:13,
],
    ...
[
    abc:1
    s:133,
]
```

A valid output:

```
abc,xy,s12,s

123,yz,13,
1,,,133
```

I'm teaching myself 'functional style' programming but I'm thinking that this problem doesn't lend itself well to a functional solution.
I believe that this problem requires some state to be kept for the output header and that subsequently each line depends on that header.

**I'm looking to solve the problem in a single pass. My goals are efficiency for a large data set, minimal traversals, and if possible, parallelizability. If this isn't possible then can you give a proof or reasoning to explain why?**

EDIT: Is there a way to solve the problem like this functionally?:

> Say you pass through the array once, in some particular order. Then
>   from the start the header set looks like `abc,xy,s12` for the first
>   object. With CSV entry `123,yz,13` . Then on the next object we add an
>   additional key to the header set so `abc,xy,s12,s` would be the header
>   and the CSV entry would be `1,,,133` . In the end we wouldn't need to
>   pass through the data set a second time. We could just append extra
>   commas to the result set. This is one way we could approach a single
>   pass....

Are there functional tools ( functions ) designed to solve problems like this, and what should I be considering? [ By functional tools I mean Monads,FlatMap, Filters, etc. ] . **Alternatively, should I be considering things like Futures ?**

Currently I've been trying to approach this using Java8, but am open to solutions from Scala, etc. Ideally I would be able to determine if Java8s' functional approach can solve the problem since that's the language I'm currently working in.

Comment: What is an `Array.json`. is this Scala ? And... `functional approach` or not is only an approach to write a solution. And what do you mean by `functional tools` ?

Comment: That was the input source. I will try to clean this up.

Comment: I will try to be more clear about functional tools.

Comment: I think the first thing that you need to understand is -- what is this `functional paradigm` ? You should read [Features of functional languages](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_programming) before proceeding any further. And if you want to learn function programming... stay clear of Java which is not a functional language.

Comment: There are very few pure functional languages so just staying clear of side effects will open for functional programming. eg. `java.lang.String` has always been functional.

Comment: @Sylwester what do you mean by `java.lang.String` being functional ? It is just `immutable`... nothing else.

Comment: I removed the pure-functional tag. https://www.infoq.com/articles/How-Functional-is-Java-8 goes into detail about how functional java is. I'm not trying to start a language debate. Just looking for 'functional style' approaches.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Correct.. No side effects and thus functional.

Comment: It can't be done in one pass. Consider: the last line of the input may change the first line of the output (since it may add an as-yet-unseen key). So you have to collect **something** as you go over the input, then at the end go over that and output the list of keys, then the lists of values. Two passes

Comment: @Paul, can you think about it this way. Say you pass through the array once, in some particular order. Then from the start the header set looks like    `abc,xy,s12` for the first object. With CSV entry `123,yz,13` . Then on the next object we add an additional key to the header set so `abc,xy,s12,s` would be the header and the CSV entry would be `1,,,133` . In the end we wouldn't need to pass through the data set a second time. We could just append extra commas to the result set. This is one way we could approach a single pass....

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul ^^ Is this reasonable?

Comment: On encountering new keys down the line, how do you add extra commas to objects that have already been processed?

Comment: If that is the biggest issue with implementing the single pass, then for the time being we can just ignore them.

Comment: To append the commas to the result set, you'd need to pass through the result set, which is going to be equivalent to passing through the input set a second time (in this case).

Comment: And how do you write out the result without taking a pass over it? That's exactly equivalent to another pass over the keys, and  you rejected several answers for doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the csv output will change with every new line of input, you must hold that in memory before writing it out. **If you consider creating an output text format** from an internal representation of a csv file **another "pass" over the data** (the internal representation of the csv is practically a `Map[String,List[String]]` which you must traverse to convert it to text) **then it's not possible to do this in a single pass.**

If, however, this is acceptable, then you can use a `Stream` to read a single item from your json file, merge that into the csv file, and do this until the stream is empty.

Assuming, that the internal representation of the csv file is

```
trait CsvFile {
  def merge(line: Map[String, String]): CsvFile
}
```

And you can represent a single item as

```
trait Item {
  def asMap: Map[String, String]
}
```

You can implement it using `foldLeft`:

```
def toCsv(items: Stream[Item]): CsvFile = 
  items.foldLeft(CsvFile(Map()))((csv, item) => csv.merge(item.asMap))
```

or use recursion to get the same result

```
@tailrec def toCsv(items: Stream[Item], prevCsv: CsvFile): CsvFile =
  items match {
    case Stream.Empty => prevCsv
    case item #:: rest =>
      val newCsv = prevCsv.merge(item.asMap)
      toCsv(rest, newCsv)
  }
```

*Note: Of course you don't have to create types for CsvFile or Item, you can use Map[String,List[String]] and Map[String,String] respectively*

UPDATE:

As more detail was requested for the `CsvFile` trait/class, here's an example implementation:

```
case class CsvFile(lines: Map[String, List[String]], rowCount: Int = 0) {
  def merge(line: Map[String, String]): CsvFile = {
    val orig = lines.withDefaultValue(List.fill(rowCount)(""))
    val current = line.withDefaultValue("")
    val newLines = (lines.keySet ++ line.keySet) map {
      k => (k, orig(k) :+ current(k))
    }
    CsvFile(newLines.toMap, rowCount + 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want, I can provide implementations for the abstract methods, or include details about `foldleft`, `@tailrec`, or using `Stream` to avoid multiple pass over the data.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions regarding tail recursion and foldLeft. Since I'm only learning functional programming I'm still grokking your code. But this looks like it meets my requirements since we only need to traverse our data set once to make the internal representation.

Comment: I'm going to play around with this a little bit and then decide but I think I will likely accept this as the solution. Thanks for helping me to learn more about 'functional style' programming!

Comment: Can you show the definition of merge? Given you need to preserve order,  and account for lines where a key does not appear, I think there's quite  a lot of computational complexity there.

Comment: Sure, I included an example implementation. If I'm not mistaken it's complexity is linear with the number of unique columns in the dataset. While the toCsv is linear with respect to the number of items. I think it's still linear with the number of lines in the input file. (But I might be wrong here)

Comment: Hi @discord if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40165821/2030737) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Its completely OK to have state in functional programming. But having mutable state or mutating state is not allowed in functional programming.

Functional programming advocates creating new changed state instead of mutating the state in place.

So, its Ok to read and access state created in the program until and unless you are mutating or side effecting.

Coming to the point.

```
val list = List(List("abc" -> "123", "xy" -> "yz"), List("abc" -> "1"))

list.map { inner => inner.map { case (k, v) => k}}.flatten

list.map { inner => inner.map { case (k, v) => v}}.flatten
```

**REPL**

```
scala> val list = List(List("abc" -> "123", "xy" -> "yz"), List("abc" -> "1"))
list: List[List[(String, String)]] = List(List((abc,123), (xy,yz)), List((abc,1)))


scala> list.map { inner => inner.map { case (k, v) => k}}.flatten
res1: List[String] = List(abc, xy, abc)

scala> list.map { inner => inner.map { case (k, v) => v}}.flatten
res2: List[String] = List(123, yz, 1)
```

or use flatMap instead of map and flatten

```
val list = List(List("abc" -> "123", "xy" -> "yz"), List("abc" -> "1"))

list.flatMap { inner => inner.map { case (k, v) => k}}

list.flatMap { inner => inner.map { case (k, v) => v}}
```

Comment: what are you trying to answer here ?

Comment: The hidden catch here is that since all the "rows" in Array.json file are `json` without a defined schema, you will never have the full set of keys till you have seen the last `json`. And what if they had any nesting ?? Also... you are supposed to produce "rows" of `values` for each "json" in same order as keys to qualify as the `csv with header`.

Comment: I tried to make it clear regarding the schema being unknown. @Singh when I wrote "array of one dimensional javascript objects" I think this implied "no nesting". Let me know if I should make this more clear.

Comment: I'm looking to solve the problem in a single pass.  I'm not sure I made that clear from the start. It's much more trivial in multiple passes.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one approach:

```
val arr = Array(Map("abc" -> 123, "xy" -> "yz", "s12" -> 13), Map("abc" -> 1, "s" -> 133)) 
    val keys = arr.flatMap(_.keys).distinct  // get the distinct keys for header
    arr.map(x => keys.map(y => x.getOrElse(y,""))) // get an array of rows
```

Comment: I'm looking to solve the problem in a single pass. My goals are efficiency for a large data set, minimal traversals, and parallelizability. Sorry I didn't state that from the start.

Answer (score 0):

In functional programming, mutable state is not allowed. But immutable states/values are fine.

Assuming that you have read your json file in to a value input:List[Map[String,String]], the codes below will solve your problem:

```
val input = List(Map("abc"->"123", "xy"->"yz" , "s12"->"13"), Map("abc"->"1", "s"->"33"))
val keys = input.map(_.keys).flatten.toSet
val keyvalues = input.map(kvs => keys.map(k => (k->kvs.getOrElse(k,""))).toMap)
val values = keyvalues.map(_.values)
val result = keys.mkString(",") + "\n" + values.map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("\n")
```

Comment: I just bolded my requirements. I think this is happening in multiple passes because you map the key set first.

Comment: I think multiple passes doesn't mean inefficiency. When you are programing in a functional way, which means there is no mutable state, you can easily make the program run concurrently. For example, in this case, you can use **input.par.map** to make the execution concurrently to improve the efficiency.

Comment: "I think multiple passes doesn't mean inefficiency." Exactly right. There's nothing magic that results from doing this in one pass.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt and insight. I'm really interested in trying to solve the problem in a single pass as I think it's more elegant. And by single pass I'm not trying to remove concurrency.